# How to correct a recursive implementation of counting equal items on matrix diagonal?

Tags: java, matrix

This recursive method for counting the number of equal elements of a n x n matrix does not work. from debugging it keeps returning the same value, stops counting and keeps i and j equal to 1. Help apreciated !

```
private static int checkSecDiag(int i,int j,int count,int col,char[][] board){
    if(i == col-1)
        return count;
    if(board[i][j] == board[i+1][j-1]) count ++;
    i++;
    j--;
    checkSecDiag(i,j,count,col,board);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: *sigh*... why do people keep illustrating recursion with programming languages that are notoriously badly suited for it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller just learning java in college, had no ideea :)

Comment: What parameters are you entering into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code ignores the return value of recursive invocation.

You should not pass `count` at all, and change the implementation as follows:

```
private static int checkSecDiag(int i, int j, int col, char[][] board){
    if(i == col-1)
        return 0;
    return checkSecDiag(i+1, j-1, col, board)
         + ((board[i][j] == board[i+1][j-1])) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

The trick to this implementation is on the last line: you return whatever the recursive step has returned, adding one if board items next to each other are the same.

Comment: @AdrianCostin Please see the edit.